# Combining different components in a single re-usable component

Tags: reactjs

I have started development with material ui framework in ReactJs and downloaded the free version of Dashboard template.

There are three broad components in the dashboard.js - AppBar, Drawer & the Cental Box item. I hope in my new project AppBar & the Drawer will remain same accross the project and I do not want to repeat the same code for AppBar & Drawer in different pages. Please suggest how to extract these into separate Component so that these can be resused accross my project.
Source :-

App URl : https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/templates/dashboard/

Source Code : https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/v5.10.7/docs/data/material/getting-started/templates/dashboard

Comment: Create a component which uses these components, and use that component throughout your application?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
What are you asking? I do not see a question, expected result or any described issue. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to create something like MasterPage, where Header, Footer and left part of the subsequent child pages will remain same.
How to achieve such feature ?

Comment: @user1368974: Have you tried anything at all?  What's stopping you from making a component which contains these other components?  You can use the built-in `children` prop to render components passed as children in the JSX structure.  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Thanks David. I managed to complete it after few tries. props.children is the key to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is MasterFile code

```
function Card(props) {
  const myClass = "card " + props.className;
  return <div className={myClass}>{props.children}</d`enter code here`iv>;
}

export default Card;
```

and below is child component

```
function ExpenseItem(props) {

  const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);


const clickHandler = ()=>   {

  setTitle('Updated!');
  setCount(count+1);
  console.log(count);
}; 

  return (
    <Card className='expense-item'>
    <ExpenseDate date = {props.date}></ExpenseDate>
      <div className='expense-item__description'>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <div className='expense-item__price'>$ {props.amount}</div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Change Title</button>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default ExpenseItem;
```